# Show an info only if it exists with $auth and vuejs (nuxt)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to show a data to the user only if it exists (so if he identify)
but i go an error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
I do not understand because i've used the v-if property to avoid that error here

```html
<template>
  <div>   
     <Navbar/>
     <p v-if="this.$auth.$storage.state.user.email"> {{ this.$auth.$storage.state.user.email }} </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Don't use `this` in the template. Also, what do you have in your state? Double check with your Vue devtools.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `this.$auth.$storage.state.user` is null.

Such as the `v-if` is on the `email` object or `user`, it throw error before checking the variable.

So, I suggest you to use this code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <p v-if="this.$auth.$storage.state.user">{{ this.$auth.$storage.state.user.email }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: `this` is not useful here since we are in the template.

Comment: @kissu I just copy/paste his code. Yes it seems not very useful but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Actually If you consider the test cases, it will be like
`this.$auth` will be valid one but it might not contain `$storage` so it might throw an error saying Cannot read `state` of undefined. The same can be applicable when you go deeper checking for attributes.
So to do this kind of check at each stage you can follow the below approach

```html
<template>
  <div>
     <p v-if="$auth?.$storage?.state?.user">{{ $auth.$storage.state.user.email }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

For optional chaining to work inside `v-if`,
install @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining and add it to  to your babel’s config plugins as @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining

Comment: You cannot use optional chaining into the template directly.

Comment: You can make it work by adding the `@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` plugin

Comment: In template? Pretty sure that you cannot since it's not an ESnext configuration issue but rather a Vue loader one. Otherwise, I could have used it for a long time already. Meanwhile, having a computed property is still fine/working.

Comment: lol I guess you missed it then

Comment: its works with that one

Comment: Apparently you can have a specific loader indeed: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11088#issuecomment-864587093 You still need to extend Webpack's configuration to make it work. Pretty surprised that it does work with vanilla JS + Webpack4 and Vue2 but it's good enough!

Comment: Still, try to recommend some solution that maybe do not require a build configuration.

Comment: Then, I feel going with the `computed` will be a right choice as of now

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that can work out of the box would be

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar />
    <p v-if="isEmailFilled">
      {{ $auth.$storage.state.user.email }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    isEmailFilled() {
      return this.$auth?.$storage?.state?.user?.email
    },
  },
}
</script>
```